# Can I multiply a vector with two columns by a database with three columns and 3939 rows?

Tags: r, dataframe, vector, multiplication

My vector has the number of stocks in two companies that I would own (without ever selling). The data frame has the date in the first column, the closing price of stock 1 in the second column, and the closing price of stock 2 in the third column.

I have tried creating a data frame to see the total value of my "portfolio" over time.

```
portfolio_value <- portfolio_number_of_stocks*portfolio[,2:3]
```

However, the error I am getting is '*' only defined for equally-sized data frames. Is there a better way to get a portfolio data frame? I feel like it should be simple but I am new to r.

Comment: Can you provide a sample of the data and your expected output?

Comment: It is definitely not clear what you want or have. Assuming your `pf_n`s are just 2 numbers ( constant weights never changing ) you could use `sweep(portfolio, 2, portfolio_number_of_stocks, '*')` which is equivalent to performing a loop. If your weights change you will have to create a `data.frame` with the same number of rows, based on the days where you have each weight. For example using `rep(weight, n)` for each weight and then creating the `data.frame`.

Comment: So essentially, I have a portfolio of two stocks that I have tracked for 3939 days. The portfolio is a database ("portfolio") with three columns: The first is the date, the second is stock1's closing price, and column 3 is stock2's closing price. I have a vector ("portfolio_number_of_stocks") that contains two numbers. (93.2 for stock 1 and 2030 for stock 2). I am trying to create a database that multiplies 93.2 by the stock1's closing price, and 2030 by stock2's closing price. Therefore, creating a data frame that shows the value of the portfolio on a given day.